# Covering space with countably many balls of given radius

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am reading a proof in "Convergence of probability measures" by Patrick Billingsley, of the following theorem: If $S$ is separable and complete, then each probability measure on ($S$, $B(S)$) is tight.

Proof starts with: Since $S$ is separable, there is, for each $k$, a sequence
$A_{k,1}, A_{k,2}, ...$ of open $\frac{1}{k}$-balls covering $S$.

I don't see why it is true.

Answer (score 3):

$S$ is separable, so there exists a countable set $C\subseteq S$ intersecting any  non-trivial open set. If you consider all open balls at radius $\frac{1}{2k}$, this would imply that $S\subseteq \bigcup_{c\in C} B_{\frac{1}{k}}(c)$ by the triangle inequality.